# Which properties I must set in a TToolbar in order to show a beveled line between the rows?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe4

Which properties I must set in a TToolbar control in order to show a beveled line between the rows of the buttons when a toolbar is set to autosize.

on this image the toolbar only show one row with buttons

[image]

If I resize the parent form the toolbar redistribute the buttons on more rows and a beveled line is added at the bottom of each row.

[image]

[image]

I tried with many properties in the TToolbar control, but not beveled line is added when the toolbar is resize.

These are the current toolbar settings

```
  object ToolBar1: TToolBar
    AlignWithMargins = True
    Left = 3
    Top = 3
    Width = 137
    Height = 74
    AutoSize = True
    BorderWidth = 1
    Caption = 'ToolBar1'
    EdgeBorders = [ebLeft, ebTop, ebRight, ebBottom]
    Images = ImageList1
    TabOrder = 0
```

And this is how looks.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should group tool buttons with separators. They can be added by right click on the toolbar and select "New Separator". In the first snapshot, there are several separators, so that line break will be shown.